# Java - best library to help draw text at arbitrary anchor points

Tags: java, swing, text, graphics2d

I'm familiar with how to use the various FontMetrics functions to center text vertically, horizontally, and whatnot.  However, I am looking for a library that supports drawing text at a given xy location relative to the string (e.g. I want the center of the string at x,y, or I want the upper right corner of it to be here, etc.)

I found [JCommon](http://www.jfree.org/jcommon/index.html) and its text anchors which purport to do that, but I am having trouble getting it to work and [the forum is heretofore unresponsive](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=29733&start=0).

I'm aware I could write all the utility functions myself but I'd like to avoid reinventing the wheel if at all possible.

Comment: From the "better late than never" department, the bug you reported in the forum has been fixed for the JCommon 1.0.20 release.  In addition, for what you were trying to achieve, the TextUtilities.drawAlignedString() method would have been the best option.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'd forgotten about this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up having to do it myself.  Code is as follows:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.font.TextLayout;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestFontLayout extends JPanel {

    public enum AnchorPoint{
        UPPER_LEFT,
        TOP_CENTER,
        UPPER_RIGHT,
        RIGHT_CENTER,
        LOWER_RIGHT,
        BOTTOM_CENTER,
        LOWER_LEFT,
        LEFT_CENTER,
        CENTER
    };

    public void drawText(TextLayout text, AnchorPoint point, Graphics2D g2, float x, float y) {
        float translationX = 0.0f;
        float translationY = 0.0f;

        Rectangle2D bounds = text.getBounds();
        float midYOffset = (float) bounds.getHeight()/2;
        float midXOffset = (float) -bounds.getWidth()/2;

        float topYOffset = (float) bounds.getHeight();
        float bottomYOffset = 0.0f;

        float leftXOffset = 0.0f;
        float rightXOffset = (float) -bounds.getWidth();

        // Adjust x values
        switch (point) {
            // Left
            case UPPER_LEFT:
            case LOWER_LEFT:
            case LEFT_CENTER:
                translationX = leftXOffset;
                break;
                // Mid
            case TOP_CENTER:
            case BOTTOM_CENTER:
            case CENTER:
                translationX = midXOffset;
                break;
            // Right
            case UPPER_RIGHT:
            case RIGHT_CENTER:
            case LOWER_RIGHT:
                translationX = rightXOffset;
        }

        // Adjust y values
        switch (point) {
            // Top
            case UPPER_LEFT:
            case UPPER_RIGHT:
            case TOP_CENTER:
                translationY = topYOffset;
                break;
            // Mid
            case LEFT_CENTER:
            case CENTER:
            case RIGHT_CENTER:
                translationY = midYOffset;
                break;
            // Bottom
            case LOWER_LEFT:
            case BOTTOM_CENTER:
            case LOWER_RIGHT:
                translationY = bottomYOffset;
        }

        text.draw(g2, x + translationX, y + translationY);

    }

    public TestFontLayout() {
        super();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        // Ensure that the default painting occurs
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Point2D loc = new Point2D.Double(getWidth()/2,getHeight()/2);
        Font font = Font.decode("Helvetica");
        FontRenderContext frc = g2.getFontRenderContext();
        TextLayout layout = new TextLayout("This is a string", font, frc);

        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2.drawRect(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2, 1,1);

        g2.setColor(Color.PINK);
        drawText(layout, AnchorPoint.UPPER_LEFT, g2, 0, 0);

        g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        drawText(layout, AnchorPoint.TOP_CENTER, g2, getWidth()/2, 0);

        g2.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        drawText(layout, AnchorPoint.UPPER_RIGHT, g2, getWidth(), 0);

        g2.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        drawText(layout, AnchorPoint.RIGHT_CENTER, g2, getWidth(), getHeight()/2);

        g2.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        drawText(layout, AnchorPoint.LOWER_RIGHT, g2, getWidth(), getHeight());

        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        drawText(layout, AnchorPoint.BOTTOM_CENTER, g2, getWidth()/2, getHeight());


        g2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        drawText(layout, AnchorPoint.LOWER_LEFT, g2, 0, getHeight());

        g2.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        drawText(layout, AnchorPoint.LEFT_CENTER, g2, 0, getHeight()/2);


        g2.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        drawText(layout, AnchorPoint.CENTER, g2, getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
        frame.add(new TestFontLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

[alt text http://grab.by/2WlM](http://grab.by/2WlM)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any libraries, but I would guess if you do it on your own your would just use the Graphics.translate() to translate the text to a relative position.

Comment: Definitely could do the translation through affine transforms.  

I'll wait until I see what the responses are in next few days; if nothing comes up I'll either try to dive into the source of JCommons and fix that bug, or write it myself.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at [`TextLayout`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextLayout.html). The [`draw()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextLayout.html#draw%28java.awt.Graphics2D,%20float,%20float%29) and [`getBounds()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextLayout.html#getBounds()) methods can simplify coding.

Answer (score 0):

I found the `TestFontLayout` code by [I82Much](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155392/i82much) to be very useful, thanks. There was a minor bug in the vertical alignment. My fix is to use `bounds.getY()` instead of `bounds.getHeight()` for the 'offset' calculation. Also, the `drawText(...)` method has been modified to return a custom `Box` class to provide the corner coordinates of the drawn text so the next drawing can use a Box corner to align more text. Here's my version of the code.

```
import static java.awt.Color.BLACK;
import static java.awt.Color.BLUE;
import static java.awt.Color.CYAN;
import static java.awt.Color.DARK_GRAY;
import static java.awt.Color.MAGENTA;
import static java.awt.Color.ORANGE;
import static java.awt.Color.PINK;
import static java.awt.Color.RED;
import static java.awt.Color.YELLOW;
import static java.awt.Font.PLAIN;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.font.TextLayout;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestFontLayout2 extends JPanel
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public enum Anchor
    {
        UPPER_LEFT,
        UPPER_CENTER,
        UPPER_RIGHT,
        MIDDLE_LEFT,
        MIDDLE_CENTER,
        MIDDLE_RIGHT,
        LOWER_LEFT,
        LOWER_CENTER,
        LOWER_RIGHT
    };

    public static Box drawText(Graphics2D g2d, String text, Anchor point, float xpos, float ypos)
    {
        return drawText(g2d, new TextLayout(text, g2d.getFont(), g2d.getFontRenderContext()), point, xpos, ypos);
    }
    
    public static Box drawText(Graphics2D g2d, String text, Anchor point, float xpos, float ypos, Font font)
    {
        return drawText(g2d, new TextLayout(text, font, g2d.getFontRenderContext()), point, xpos, ypos);
    }
    
    public static Box drawText(Graphics2D g2d, TextLayout text, Anchor anchor, float xpos, float ypos)
    {
        Rectangle2D bounds = text.getBounds();

        float xOffsetLeft = 0.0f;
        float xOffsetRight = (float) -bounds.getWidth();
        float xOffsetCenter = (float) -bounds.getWidth() / 2.0f;
        
        // Bounds.getY() is the (negative) offset between the baseline and the top of the text.
        // Bounds.getHeight() is the distance above plus the distance below the text baseline.
        float yOffsetTop = (float) bounds.getY();
        float yOffsetBottom = (float) (bounds.getHeight()+bounds.getY());
        float yOffsetMiddle = (float) (-bounds.getHeight()) / 2.0f;
        
        float xOffset = 0.0f;
        float yOffset = 0.0f;

        // Adjust x values
        switch (anchor)
        {
            // Left
            case UPPER_LEFT:
            case MIDDLE_LEFT:
            case LOWER_LEFT:
                xOffset = xOffsetLeft;
                break;
            // Center
            case UPPER_CENTER:
            case MIDDLE_CENTER:
            case LOWER_CENTER:
                xOffset = xOffsetCenter;
                break;
            // Right
            case UPPER_RIGHT:
            case MIDDLE_RIGHT:
            case LOWER_RIGHT:
                xOffset = xOffsetRight;
                break;
        }

        // Adjust y values
        switch (anchor)
        {
            // Top
            case UPPER_LEFT:
            case UPPER_CENTER:
            case UPPER_RIGHT:
                yOffset = yOffsetTop;
                break;
            // Middle
            case MIDDLE_LEFT:
            case MIDDLE_CENTER:
            case MIDDLE_RIGHT:
                yOffset = yOffsetMiddle;
                break;
            // Bottom
            case LOWER_LEFT:
            case LOWER_CENTER:
            case LOWER_RIGHT:
                yOffset = yOffsetBottom;
                break;
        }
        
        // Draw text at baseline position.
        float xbase = xpos + xOffset;
        float ybase = ypos - yOffset;
        text.draw(g2d, xbase, ybase);
        
        // Enclose text within a box.
        int xrect = rnd(xbase + bounds.getX());
        int yrect = rnd(ybase + bounds.getY());
        int wrect = rnd(bounds.getWidth());
        int hrect = rnd(bounds.getHeight());
        Box box = new Box(xrect, yrect, xrect+wrect, yrect+hrect);

        // Debug: draw rectangle around text.
        // g2d.drawRect(xrect, yrect, wrect, hrect);
        
        return box;
    }
    
    private static int rnd(double value)
    {
        return (int) Math.round(value);
    }

    public static class Box
    {
        private int tl[] = {0, 0}; public int[] getTL() { return tl; }
        private int br[] = {0, 0}; public int[] getBR() { return br; }
        private int tr[] = {0, 0}; public int[] getTR() { return tr; }
        private int bl[] = {0, 0}; public int[] getBL() { return bl; }
        
        public Box(int tlx, int tly, int brx, int bry)
        {
            tl[0] = tlx; tl[1] = tly;
            br[0] = brx; br[1] = bry;
            tr[0] = brx; tr[1] = tly;
            bl[0] = tlx; bl[1] = bry;
        }
    }

    public TestFontLayout2()
    {
        super();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,300));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        
        // Ensure that the default painting occurs
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Font font = new Font("SansSerif", PLAIN, 21);
        FontRenderContext frc = g2d.getFontRenderContext();
        TextLayout layout1 = new TextLayout("This is a string", font, frc);
        TextLayout layout2 = new TextLayout("This is text", font, frc);

        g2d.setColor(RED);
        g2d.drawRect(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2, 1,1);

        g2d.setColor(PINK);
        Box box = drawText(g2d, layout1, Anchor.UPPER_LEFT, 0, 0);

        g2d.setColor(BLUE);
        box = drawText(g2d, layout2, Anchor.UPPER_CENTER, getWidth()/2, 0);

        g2d.setColor(ORANGE);
        box = drawText(g2d, layout1, Anchor.UPPER_RIGHT, getWidth(), 0);

        g2d.setColor(DARK_GRAY);
        box = drawText(g2d, layout2, Anchor.MIDDLE_LEFT, 0, getHeight()/2);

        g2d.setColor(MAGENTA);
        box = drawText(g2d, layout1, Anchor.MIDDLE_CENTER, getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);
        box = drawText(g2d, layout1, Anchor.UPPER_LEFT, box.getBL()[0], box.getBL()[1]);

        g2d.setColor(CYAN);
        box = drawText(g2d, layout2, Anchor.MIDDLE_RIGHT, getWidth(), getHeight()/2);

        g2d.setColor(YELLOW);
        box = drawText(g2d, layout1, Anchor.LOWER_LEFT, 0, getHeight());

        g2d.setColor(BLACK);
        box = drawText(g2d, layout2, Anchor.LOWER_CENTER, getWidth()/2, getHeight());

        g2d.setColor(ORANGE);
        box = drawText(g2d, layout1, Anchor.LOWER_RIGHT, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        println("Draw text at specified anchor points...");
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
        frame.add(new TestFontLayout2());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    private static void println(Object obj)
    {
        System.out.println(obj.toString());
    }
}
// vi:set tabstop=4 hardtabs=4 shiftwidth=4 expandtab:
```