# Creating labels along with drawlines

Tags: java, swing

I have asked a question regarding custom widget but confused to whether I need it and how should proceed.

I have currently this class

```
public class GUIEdge {

   public Node node1;
   public Node node2;
   public int weight;
   public Color color;
    public GUIEdge(Node node1, Node node2 , int cost) {
       this.node1 = node1;
       this.node2 = node2;
       this.weight = cost;
       this.color = Color.darkGray;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        Point p1 = node1.getLocation();
        Point p2 = node2.getLocation();
        g.setColor(this.color);
        ((Graphics2D) g).setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);

    }
}
```

Currently this draws an edge between two points but now I want that a label for the cost also gets created along with it.

I have already added handling for dragging of node and edges so what is the best way to create the label

Do I need to make a custom widget for that ? Could anyone explain that suppose making a component by extending from JComponent then I'll call it by g.mixed() where mixed is that new widget...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tool tips are certainly worth a look. Other choices include [`drawString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html), [`translate()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html), or [`TextLayout`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextLayout.html). There are many [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%5Bswing%5D+TextLayout) available.

Addendum: The example below shows both `drawString()` and `setToolTipText()`, as suggested by @Catalina Island. For [simplicity](http://sscce.org/), the endpoints are relative to the component's size, so you can see the result of resizing the window.

Addendum: This use of `setToolTipText()` merely demonstrates the approach. As @camickr notes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398471), you should override `getToolTipText(MouseEvent)` and update the tip when the mouse is over the line or when the line is selected.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394364 */
public class LabeledEdge extends JComponent {

    private static final int N = 20;
    private Point n1, n2;

    public LabeledEdge(int w, int h) {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w, h));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.n1 = new Point(N, N);
        this.n2 = new Point(getWidth() - N, getHeight() - N);
        g.drawLine(n1.x, n1.y, n2.x, n2.y);
        double d = n1.distance(n2);
        this.setToolTipText(String.valueOf(d));
        g.drawString(String.valueOf((int) d),
            (n1.x + n2.x) / 2, (n1.y + n2.y) / 2);
    }

    private static void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("EdgeLabel");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new LabeledEdge(320, 240));
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer but could you explain more as in how is translate going to help ??? And also like if I use textLayout ... then I have that since edge connects a node when I drag node edge too gets updated... but its text would need to be updated too...how can i do that ?

Comment: I'd start with `drawString()` in your `draw()` method, as seen in this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278474/java-best-library-to-help-draw-text-at-arbitrary-anchor-points/2412059#2412059).

Comment: In this would moving the node ( changes the edge as well ) drag the string along side it ?

Comment: Thanks a lot .... I believe it should be + in both for g.drawString and you should correct it for whoever looks at it afterwards but it helped a lot .... :)

Comment: Excellent! That hugs the edge better, and it's simpler too.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `GUIEdge extends JComponent`. That way you'd get tool tip labels automatically.

Comment: Could you tell how will I use it ? As in then I can directly set tooltip of GUIEdge equal to weight ?

Comment: There's examples in the [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html). I'd do it in the constructor, where `weight` gets set.

Comment: Can you help please ? I am using edge as e.draw() in the function to create edges ... I have added e.setToolTipText() in the constructor as well as where I am drawing the edge so that repainting it could again set the tooltext .... but it is not happening...