# Setting tool tip text for a graphic object

Tags: java, swing, tooltip

Is there a way to set tool tip text for a drawn line ?

I have looked at [stackoverflowques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394364/creating-labels-along-with-drawlines) and tried its answer but its not working.

In my program I have also looked at extending to JComponent but am facing the problem that when I set a value of ToolTextTip in paintComponent after drawing the line it is not shown on the screen.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating labels along with drawlines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394364/creating-labels-along-with-drawlines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use setToolTipText() in the paintComponent() method.

If anything you should be overriding getToolTipText(MouseEvent), to determine when the mouse is over the line and then set the tool tip.

Comment: +1 I've updated this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396931) to reflect this important point.